# How to upload video programmatically from iPhone app to youtube?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, youtube

I need to upload video on YouTube from iPhone app. I am creating video from images and audio file. This created video needs to be uploaded on YouTube. I am not getting any link for how to upload video on YouTube. I am working on xcode 4.6?

Please please let me know if any one have an idea about uploading video on YouTube. I spent lots of time but didn't getting any output.

Comment: Have you looked through their API documentation?

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy, but I need demo app how to implemented API in iPhone app

Comment: @suhas I m wondering that you have asked seven question but not accept any answer

Comment: Try this: http://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE : Youtube has released Youtube API 3.0 and 2.0 is now Deprecated. Refer official document for more detail : [YouTube for Developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)**

I have never done this but I m sure following link will help you.

1. [YouTube API v2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Uploading_Videos)
2. [gdata-objectivec-client](https://github.com/nparry/gdata-objectivec-client/tree/) 
   2.1 [Upload Videos to YouTube with iPhone custom App](http://urinieto.com/2010/10/upload-videos-to-youtube-with-iphone-custom-app/)

Comment: thank CRDave, I spend lot of time for above links but not getting any good result.

Comment: on link 2.1 some people have commented error and some solution try that out. All the best.....

Comment: thanks a lots CRDave, Above links are good & useful  but we need to solve some issue

Comment: YouTube API is now up to 3.0 https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/